# Scroll to specific list item in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I make Fake ExandableListView(Adapter) with ListView(Adapter). (Because I need more customizing)

One List Item contains GroupView and ChildView (default visibility is gone)

Then I change visibility of child view.

```
public void itemClicked(int position) {
    Group group = groupData.get(position);
    Child child = childData.get(group);
    View childView = child.getChildView();
    if (group.toggleExpansion()) {
        childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I need auto-scroll when expand list item , like real ExpandableListView

How can I auto scroll to show child?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29

Comment: @Raghunandan setSelection make item is on top. It was not my wish. I want scroll available minimum scrolling.

Comment: check the other methods in the same link  smoothScrollToPosition or smoothScrollByOffset  dependign on your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I did it.

If just use smoothScrollToPosition() => It show only group view not child view.

So I add OnLayoutChangeListener in ListView. Like this.

```
private int expandedPosition;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private boolean addOnLayoutChangeListener() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return false;
    }

    listView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            LogUtils.pi("onLayoutChange");
            if (expandedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(expandedPosition);
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        boolean expanded = adapter.itemClicked(position);
        if (expanded) {
            expandedPosition = position;
        } else {
            expandedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
        }
}
```